# Errors relating to gdi32 when trying to use pdcurses-extended library

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, gdi, pdcurses

Specs:

OS: Windows 7

IDE: Codeblocks

Compiler: GNU GCC compiler

Library: [PDCurses-extended](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses)

Library build platform: WinGUI (Windows Graphics Mode) using the Makefile.mng located in PDCurses-master\wingui

---

Problem:

After installing and linking the PDCurses-extended library, I tried to compile and run a simple Hello World program to check if everything is set up correctly:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){

    initscr();                  /* Start curses mode */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World */
    refresh();                  /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();                    /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();                   /* End curses mode */

    return 0;
}
```

But after trying to compile the code I got the following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in pdcurs_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `Rectangle@20'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `Rectangle@20'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `GetTextMetricsW@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `GetTextMetricsW@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcscrn.o):pdcscrn.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `CreateFontIndirectW@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `ChooseFontW@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `CommDlgExtendedError@0'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SetBkColor@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `ExtTextOutW@32'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `CreatePen@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `MoveToEx@16'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `LineTo@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `MoveToEx@16'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `LineTo@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `MoveToEx@16'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `LineTo@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `MoveToEx@16'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `LineTo@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `MoveToEx@16'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `LineTo@12'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\PDCurses-master\wingui\pdcurses.a(pdcdisp.o):pdcdisp.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 41 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

After searching online for a solution, I have found out that I must link the gdi32 library using -lgdi32 in the linker options, but that didn't seem to work. I have also tried to include the windows.h library using

```
#include <windows.h>
```

at the beginning of the code, but again to no avail.

---

Am I even able to utilize the windows GUI using C, or am I required to use C++?

Is the error generated because I made a mistake in making the Makefile, or perhaps linking the library, do I need to install another library, or is it just something I'm still unaware of?

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my own problem.

I incorrectly linked the gdi32 library.

For anyone having the same problem, go to:

Settings > Compiler > Linker settings > Link libraries > Add >

and find the libgdi32.a (mine was located at C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib)